# Fetching in reactjs doesn't work after deploying in github pages

Tags: reactjs, fetch, github-pages

So I have a reactjs app publish in github pages, is this one https://bernardoolisan.github.io/PyOcr/
The problem is that the app fetch data, but when I deploy it on github pages it give this error:
[image]

And it was working:(

And now my page doesn't work too, it was working but right now is blank i dont know why

Comment: Please share some code of how you are fetching the data so we could help .

Comment: @MahdiFaraji the whole code is in here https://github.com/BernardoOlisan/PyOcr, "src>app.js"

Comment: also it does not work on netlify

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are deploying the react project the wrong way to hosting providers such as github or netlify . First you must build your react project and then only push the files inside the build folder to hosting provider . Github pages can only serve static html css js files so it can only serve the build folder of your react project .

**Note**

To build a react app you can run `npm run build` and a build folder will be generated . Then you can push the files inside of the build folder to github repository and enable github pages for it .

Comment: Any alternatives for deployment?

Comment: @BernardoOlisan I added extra notes on how to build the project and push it to github pages .

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, and I too though gh-pages can't fetch data. But what I did was I added cors to my server. I allowed cross-origin requests. Now it retrieves data from my server on heroku.